# why my ipython notebook didn't show result?

Tags: python, ipython

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 12)
import seaborn as sns
all_sets=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\champion\Desktop\ch02\AllSets-x.json")
df_list=[]
for i in all_sets.columns.values:
    deck=allset[str(i)]["card"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(deck)
    df_list.append(df)
all_cards = pd.concat(df_list)
all_cards.cmc.fillna(0)
all_cards.reset_index(inplace=True)
all_cards.columns.values
```

when I exceuted my code,result didn't show.
And ipython notebook have IN[*] in right.

Comment: Maybe it is busy (still executing code)? Try breaking the code into more cells and executing intermediate results.

Comment: I has executed the code,and tried to break the code,but ipython didn't show result.